# PHP - is mysql_prep deprecated

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, deprecated

I'm working on a login form and am using some code from a tutorial.
Now I don't remember what the mysql_prep was for and whether it's deprecated, since it's not mysqli... I couldn't really make sense of what I googled.

Is it ok to use this or should I use something else or not use it all together?

It looks like this (variables used to update SQL table):

```html
$username = mysql_prep($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysql_prep($_POST["password"]);
$hashed_password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Any function that starts with `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: And it is removed as of PHP 7

Comment: It would appear that is a local function. There is nothing on it in the [manual](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysql_prep&scope=quickref)

Comment: oh dear you're right... sorry for the bother.. i'm gonna delete this question! sorry again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_prep must be some user defined function.  It does not exist in the php docs.

http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysql_prep&scope=quickref

Look inside this function in your own code and if it has any references to mysql_ functions then consider it deprecated.  All mysql_ functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed in PHP 7.

Use mysqli_ functions or PDO instead.